# Can I control different progressbars for different ajax events?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with two places that use ajax to submit the information to server.

```
 $("#loading img").ajaxStart(function(){ // this progress bar is used by both ajax submission.
   $(this).show();
 }).ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });

 <div id="loading">
<img src="loading4.gif" border="0" />
</div>

 $('#countyForm').ajaxForm(options); // Case I: use ajax to submit the form


 $('form#carSelect').change(function(){ // Case II: use ajax to submit the field
$.ajax({
    ...
   }
 });
});
```

How can I customize the ajax in jQuery so that I can use different progressbar for different ajax submission.

Say for case I, I use image1 and case II I use image2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Similar jsFiddle Example w/o ajaxForm**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5hdM/)

Instead of using Ajaxstart and stop, just show the individualized loading image first, then fire the Ajax directly. Ajaxstop fires when all the ajax is done on a page. You want individualized attention.

The ajaxForm plugin allows for a callback function for after the AJAX has fired. Use this to remove your custom animation. Separately bind a click event handler to the form's submit button to load that custom animation. I haven't used that plugin, so there may be an easier way.

For the other case, simply load the custom image, call the AJAX and remove the image on success.

```
// Case I --------------------------------

// Bind the event handler to the #countyForm submit button
$("#countyForm:submit").click(function() {
    // Throw in the customized loading animation when the form is submitted.
    $("#idToShowLoading1").html('<img src="custom1.gif" />');
    // .ajaxForm() handles the AJAX and the success.
});

// Make use of ajaxForm to handle your form 
$('#countyForm').ajaxForm(function() {
    // remove loading img
    $("#idToShowLoading1").html('');
    // Haven't used this plugin, but your options, etc here
});

// Case II --------------------------------

$("form#carSelect").change(function() {
    // First throw in the customized loading animation
    $("#idToShowLoading2").html('<img src="custom2.gif" />');
    // Then make the Ajax call. 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'yoururlhere.html/blah.php',
      success: function(data) {
        // remove loading img or replace it w/ content
        $("#idToShowLoading2").html('');
        // success stuff goes here         
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Peter,

Thank you for your helps.
One more step that we may add to this code is to handle the ending event both in success and error.

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 - Take a look at the .ajax() documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . For handling errors, simply add, in addition to the already present `success:` callback function an `error:` callback function (#2 under callback functions on the referenced page).

Comment: Thank you for this further helps:)